# MySQL update query with subquery using max function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb, inner-join

Can anyone see what is wrong with the below query?

```
update sub set name='dd' where salary=(select max(salary) from sub);
```

After executing errors found and MariaDB says that,

> SQL query: Documentation
>
> update sub set name='dd' where salary=(select max(salary) from sub)
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> \ #1093 - Table 'sub' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not allowed in MySQL. You can use a `join` instead:

```
update sub s
inner join (select max(salary) salary from sub) m on m.salary = s.salary
set s.name = 'dd'
```